# Return matching items from a list using SPEL

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have a scenario where i need to get the sublist of matching items from a list which satisfies the conditions.
The conditions are built dynamically.
While i was able to determine if the list contains elements matching given conditions, i couldn't extract the sublist out of it.
I need help to figure that out.

Example given below.

These are my classes:

```
class Employees {

    private List<Name> names;

    public Employees(List<Name> names) {
        this.names = names;
    }

    public Boolean containsMatchingValues(String firstName, String lastName) {
        return this.getNames().stream().anyMatch(name ->
            name.getFirstName().equals(firstName)
                && name.getLastName().equals(lastName));
    }

    public List<Name> getNames() {
        return names;
    }
}

class Name {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

And my test:

```
@Test
void testAnother() {
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Name n1 = new Name("abc", "pqr");
    Name n2 = new Name("qwe", "zxc");
    Name n3 = new Name("fgh", "rty");
    List<Name> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add(n1);
    names.add(n2);
    names.add(n3);
    Employees employees = new Employees(names);
    EvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext(employees);
    String expression = "(containsMatchingValues('abc','pqr') or containsMatchingValues('xyz','asd') or containsMatchingValues('iop','bnm'))  or  (containsMatchingValues('qwe','zxc') and  (containsMatchingValues('fgh','rty') or containsMatchingValues('cvb','hjk') or containsMatchingValues('dvu','mqa')))";
    Boolean value = parser.parseExpression(expression).getValue(context, Boolean.class);
    System.out.println(value); //true
}

@Test
void testAnother2() {
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Name n2 = new Name("qwe", "zxc");
    Name n3 = new Name("fgh", "rty");
    List<Name> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add(n2);
    names.add(n3);
    Employees employees = new Employees(names);
    EvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext(employees);
    String expression = "(containsMatchingValues('abc','pqr') or containsMatchingValues('xyz','asd') or containsMatchingValues('iop','bnm'))  or  (containsMatchingValues('qwe','zxc') and  (containsMatchingValues('fgh','rty') or containsMatchingValues('cvb','hjk') or containsMatchingValues('dvu','mqa')))";
    Boolean value = parser.parseExpression(expression).getValue(context, Boolean.class);
    System.out.println(value); //true
}

@Test
void testAnother3() {
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Name n2 = new Name("qwe", "zxc");
    List<Name> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add(n2);
    Employees employees = new Employees(names);
    EvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext(employees);
    String expression = "(containsMatchingValues('abc','pqr') or containsMatchingValues('xyz','asd') or containsMatchingValues('iop','bnm'))  or  (containsMatchingValues('qwe','zxc') and  (containsMatchingValues('fgh','rty') or containsMatchingValues('cvb','hjk') or containsMatchingValues('dvu','mqa')))";
    Boolean value = parser.parseExpression(expression).getValue(context, Boolean.class);
    System.out.println(value); //false
}
```